# can I know if a function is called directly or via an assigned variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assuming I have a function `def f(): print 0` and I want to create another function `g`, however `g`'s implementation is identical to `f`, so I just assign `f` to it:

```
def f():
    print 0
g = f
```

*you might ask, if they are identical, why use 2 functions, and that is because logically, they represent 2 different things*

Now, can I know who was called? I want to debug `f()` only when it is called via `g`. Is the flow different between this 2 calls?

***The dup suggestion has nothing to do with my question. I know the function's name, as only one function exists. I just hope to get one step further and understand if a variable that has the same value as the function name was triggered...***

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog That duplicate is invalid, as `g.__name__ == "f"` where the expected result is `"g"`.

Comment: @iBug ah ok I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, at least not this way, as Python does not track "which reference to the object is looked". I *strongly* recommend that you make `g` another function that wraps up `f`, for a less painful debugging experience.

However, if your code follows some patterns, you may have a chance by looking at `inspect.stack()`:

```
import inspect

def f():
    stack = inspect.stack()
    print(stack[1].code_context[0].strip())

g = f
f()
g()
```

Luckily, you'll get

```
f()
g()
```

If you have some regex skills, you can actually extract the function name with one:

```
import re
func_name_re = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)\s*\()")

line = "f()"
print(func_name_re.search(line).group(1))
```

However, you'll easily run into trouble identifying the real function if your calling code gets *marginally* more complex:

```
some = f(g())
some[f()] = g()
some = f("aaa g() sss")  # string content looks like function call
some = re.compile(r"^f(?!$)", flags=g())  # same as above
```

In all the above examples, you have significant difficulty trying to determine if it's `f` or `g`.

Comment: I'll refrain from atrocities such as this f(g(h()))

Comment: @CIsForCookies Well, still, I recommend you wrap it up if you want this for debugging purposes. But anyway, my solution *should* work for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work.

**input:**

```
def f():
    pass

g = f

print(f.__name__)
print(g.__name__)

print(id(f))
print(id(g))
```

**output:**

```
f
f
4350036880
4350036880
```

Only workaround I can think of would be creating some type of wrapper around the functions that calls eval and handling that way(but most likely doesn't make sense for what you will want to do). Then you could call that wrapper with a func_name argument.

```
func_name = 'f'

if func_name =='f':
    ## you know f was called
    eval('f()')
```

Comment: `eval()` is evil

Comment: I agree.  Just throwing an idea out there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that without additional helpers or code analysis.

Even the stack is not aware of the called name:

```
>>> def a(): traceback.print_stack()
... 
>>> b = a
>>> a()
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in a
>>> b()
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in a
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the simplest solution ?

```
def f():
    print 0


def g():
   return f()
```

Now you know clearly when `f` was called via `g` - you just have to inspect the call stack.

Comment: I agree there is a high likelihood this a much better design decision, but this doesn't answer the OPs question.

Comment: @user2263572 depends on which part you consider as being "the question". It doesn't answer the question's title indeed, but perfectly address the final "Now, can I know who was called? I want to debug f() only when it is called via g" one;-)

Comment: this is actually a very simple and good solution. I fell in love with the abilty to assign functions to variables and oversaw the basics...